# Bootstrap fix DIV no wrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

hi i have small problem when i resize my window i get at last BOOTSTRAP BREAKPOINRT wraping DIV is there any fix for it ? adding `ROW` doesnt helps =\

LIVE Prewiew : http://nekonomagic.sk/stylmejker/pages/uvod.php

Prewiew [image] [image]

HTML Code :

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="no-wrap">
            <div class="row col-md-1" id="slider-span">
                <a href="#" data-toggle=""><span class="fa fa-arrow-left"></span></a>
                <a href="#" data-toggle=""><span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" id="slider-pagin">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li><a href="#" id="playfair-14" data-toggle="">01</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="playfair-14" data-toggle="">02</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" id="playfair-14" data-toggle="">03</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you elaborate more what are your trying to achieve ?

Comment: no WRAP - Page Switch and Pagination for slider as you can see on Prewiew  Divs wrap when screen is changed

Comment: wait can you update your code on jsbin?/

Comment: upload your code on jsbin and provide the link

Comment: not passible cause i use FA and other css that need be imported true file and i dont have PRO account on JSBIN i can give here CSS for 

.pagination and .slider span or LIVE preview on my Testing Site

Comment: @Ashishsah HERE is LIVE PREWIEV http://nekonomagic.sk/stylmejker/pages/uvod.php

Comment: Okk do you have acess to the css

Comment: @PatrikHorváth are you looking for this [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wZIF.png ] 
at screen 990px ?

Comment: @MostafaBaezid yea this part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an instant solution, you can try this media query.

```
   @media only screen and (max-width:990px){
        #no-wrap {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
            align-items: center;
        }
        #slider-pagin{
           top:0;
        }
       }
```

Comment: Works :) Thanks a lot